# I want my list items change while pressing

Tags: android, listview

In my application the first screen is a list with four TextViews, the first one is the name of the object and the other three are some preview data from the activity behind each item.

I would like to show some extra information while pressing the element and that disappears when releasing.

Does anyone knows how to do this?I've searched but I didn't find anything similar.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no "clicking" as many devices have touch screens only. Are you asking while the user is pressing on an item - to show more details, then on release to hide them again? If so, in my opinion, this is a very bad UI design as it is not intuitive.

Comment: The closest thing is the Contextual Menu (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), which is typically used for long presses and typically displays options relevant to the pressed item.  It sounds like you want to do something similar to the iOS "popover", which you can do via an OnItemClickListener on your ListView.

Comment: Yes Graham, What I want is that, I now normally is not very intuitive but I think it would fit perfectly in mine. Actually it was an UI design expert who sugested it because is an info that you are just going to need in very especific times.

Comment: CSmith, thats not exactly what I'm looking for but if I don't find anything usefull with the other way I'll give it a try. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    yourListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        int getAction = arg1.getAction();
        switch (getAction) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                 yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;  
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                yourTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        return true;
        }
        });

   }
```

Comment: I'll gove ot try tomorrow as I don't have my code right now. Thank you!

Comment: It works for changing the view while pressing but it desactivates the OnClickListener! Any suggestions?? Thank you very much!